# Pattern for consuming data with recursive requests

Tags: python, rest, join, recursion, drilldown

There is external REST endpoint `/getCourses`, returns

```
{"course": 25.0, "setDoc":  "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF”}.
```

There is `/getDoc`, returns

```
{
   "docID": 12345, 
   "DocGuid":  "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF",
   "currencyGuid": "6da7855f-4d2d-460d-8e8d-89ce4d3c51b5”
}
```

There is `/currencyCatalog`, returns

```
{
   "currencyGuid": "6da7855f-4d2d-460d-8e8d-89ce4d3c51b5",
   "currencyDescription": "UAH”
}
```

I need to get result like

```
{ "currency": "UAH", "course": 25.0 }
```

And there are a lot of similiar tasks where I have to drill down by guids or keys and make somewhat like SQL JOINs. And for every task I have to write specific long function which makes loops of requests with error handling ans so on.

Is there any pattern/module which helps dealing with such recursive requests?